# Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense coloring

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

As you can see by this image, it's a little difficult to tell the difference between the current argument and the remaining arguments because the current argument is only slightly more bolder then the others.

I find myself scanning the line several times to catch it.

Can someone please tell me which property to change in:

`Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->???`

So I can more-easily identify which is the current argument.

[image: Circled, are the elements of the UI's intellisense that I'd wish to change.]

Comment: Fonts and Colors > Show settings for = Statement Completion.  Pick a font with a better bold style.  Default is Segoe UI, it has an excellent bold.

Comment: Well it's the right spot, the font is already Segoe UI.. can't change the colour, which is what I really wanted. Thanks just the same.

Comment: @carny666, as far as I know, there is no such option to setting this and you can report this user voice to the VS Product Team: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide